# Protractor synchrozation - timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I am writing simple protractor test four our application:

- login page is without angularhs - working fine
- all other pages are with angularjs

When i want to write angularhs test - i got this error (following [this](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/protractor-setup) installation) :

```
Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 40002ms. Please see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md
```

Config:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['login-spec.js'],
  baseUrl: 'https:/xyz/',
  allScriptsTimeout: 40000,

  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  }
}
```

And my spec:

```
describe('Login #1', function() {
  // BEFORE LOGIN
  it('should pass to next login step', function() {
    browser.driver.get('https://xyz/login');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.css(".factorFirst > [name='username']:first-child")).sendKeys('123456');

    .... other login stuff

  }, 90000);

  // AFTER LOGIN TEST
  it('Simple Angular Test', function() {
    browser.get('/page');

    element(by.model('payment.userSpecified.message')).sendKeys(1);

  }, 45000);


});
```

We don't have in our `body` element attribute `ng-app`. Can this be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let `protractor` know that the login page is non-angular and it doesn't need to wait for angular to "settle down". Set the `ignoreSynchronization` to `true` before login and set it back to `false` after:

```
describe('Login #1', function() {

  afterEach(function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
  });

  it('should pass to next login step', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    browser.driver.get('https://xyz/login');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.css(".factorFirst > [name='username']:first-child")).sendKeys('123456');
  }, 90000);

  it('Simple Angular Test', function() {
    browser.get('/page');

    element(by.model('payment.userSpecified.message')).sendKeys(1);

  }, 45000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for response. When i set 'browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;' in ANGULAR test i actually get timeout error. When i set it to TRUE -> i can sendKeys to model. But then i must work with future objects.

Comment: @Mato.Duris yeah, that's what I am saying - when you are on a non-angular page, you need to have `ignoreSynchronization` to be `true`. After it, when you come to an angular page - set it back to the default `false` value. Have you tried the code I've provided? Thanks.

Comment: This works : http://pastebin.com/uYRrB7ks ... when i have removed 'browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;' -> i have received timeout error. (afterEach function i have added as you recomended). Its is strange. Test works but i need to work with future object what is drawback.

Comment: @Mato.Duris correct me if I'm wrong. The code I've proposed helped but you are not sure if it is reliable, or don't understand how did it help? I can add more details about why I think you should solve it this way. Lmk.

Comment: Yes helped :-) But i must have set "browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;'" in ANGULAR test. What i don`t understand - why i must set it to TRUE ? My current working test : http://pastebin.com/LdGDCJMa

Comment: I strongly susspect that missing "ng-app" in our APP on body element is causing problems with synchronization. After setup of `ignoreSynchronization ` to `true` is everything working fine. (no `$timeout` pooling on page)